# Where are these "without" methods in Rails gems getting defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, metaprogramming

I've seen a few places where `*_without_*` methods are being referenced in gems, and I don't see where they're being defined.  Here are two examples from the `validationgroup` and `delayed_jobs` gems.

1. In [validation_group.rb](https://github.com/akira/validationgroup/blob/master/lib/validation_group.rb), there is a method `add_with_validation_group` that is defined that references `add_without_validation_group` on its last line; however, `add_without_validation_group` does not appear to be defined anywhere.

   ```
   def add_with_validation_group(attribute,
                                 msg = @@default_error_messages[:invalid], *args,
                                 &block)
     add_error = true
     if @base.validation_group_enabled?
       current_group = @base.current_validation_group
       found = ValidationGroup::Util.current_and_ancestors(@base.class).
         find do |klass|
           klasses = klass.validation_group_classes
           klasses[klass] && klasses[klass][current_group] &&
           klasses[klass][current_group].include?(attribute)
         end
       add_error = false unless found
     end
     add_without_validation_group(attribute, msg, *args,&block) if add_error
   end
   ```
2. In DelayedJob's [message_sending.rb](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/message_sending.rb), dynamically passed method parameters are being called as `#{method}_without_send_later`.  However, I only see where `#{method}_with_send_later` is being defined anywhere in this gem.

   ```
   def handle_asynchronously(method)
     without_name = "#{method}_without_send_later"
     define_method("#{method}_with_send_later") do |*args|
       send_later(without_name, *args)
     end
     alias_method_chain method, :send_later
   end
   ```

So my belief is that there's some Rails magic I'm missing with these "without" methods.  However, I can't seem to figure out what to search for in Google to answer the question on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's what `alias_method_chain` is providing you.

Basically when you say

```
alias_method_chain :some_method, :feature
```

You are provided two methods:

```
some_method_with_feature
some_method_without_feature
```

What happens is that when the original `some_method` is called, it actually calls `some_method_with_feature`.  Then you get a reference to `some_method_without_feature` which is your original method declaration (ie for fallback/default behavior).  So, you'll want to define `some_method_with_feature` to actually do stuff, which, as I say, is called when you call `some_method`

Example:

```
def do_something
  "Do Something!!"
end

def do_something_with_upcase
  do_something_without_upcase.upcase
end

alias_method_chain :do_something, :upcase

do_something # => "DO SOMETHING!!"
```

See the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_method_chain):